# SupplyAsync wait for all CompletableFutures to finish

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I'm running some async tasks below and need to wait until they all finish. I'm not sure why but the `join()` isn't forcing a wait for all tasks and the code continues executing without waiting. Is there a reason why the stream of joins isn't working as expected?

The CompletableFutures list is just a stream that maps supplyAsync

```
List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = items
                .stream()
                .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  {

                    System.out.println("processing");
                    // do some processing here
                    return item;

                }))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And I wait for the futures like.

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
                .thenApply(ignored -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I'm able to get the wait working with `futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);` but I wanted to know why my stream approach wasn't working.

Comment: Did you tried waiting on the resulting completable future of `CompletableFuture.allOf().thenApply()`? You just create a new future and do no operations on it.

Comment: Isn't that what my `CompletableFuture.allOf().thenApply()` should already be doing? It joins each of the futures which should be blocking until all futures are completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
                .thenApply(ignored -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Does **not** wait for all futures in `futures` to complete. What it does is create a new future that will wait for all async executions in `futures` to complete before it itself completes (but will not block until all those futures complete). When this *allOf* future completes, then your `thenApply` code runs. But `allOf()` will return immediately without blocking.

This means `futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())` in your code only runs **after** all async executions complete, which defeats your purpose. The `join()` calls will all return immediately. But this is not the bigger problem. Your challenge is that `allOf().thenApply()` will not wait for async executions to complete. It will just create another future that won't block.

The easiest solution is to use the first pipeline and map to an Integer list:

```
List<Integer> results = items.stream()
    .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        System.out.println("processing " + item);
        // do some processing here
        return item;

    }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) //force-submit all
    .stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join) //wait for each
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to use something like your original code, then your second snippet would have to be changed to:

```
List<Integer> reuslts = futures.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That's because [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) does not wait, it just combines all futures into a new one that completes when all complete:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete.

Alternatively, you could still use `allOf()` with `join()`, then run your current `thenApply()` code:

```
//wrapper future completes when all futures have completed
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
        .join(); 

//join() calls below return immediately
List<Integer> result = futures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `join()` calls in the last statement return immediately, becaues the `join()` call on the wrapper (`allOf()`) future will have waited for all futures passed to it to complete. This is why I don't see the reason to do this when you can use the first approach.

Comment: I don’t see, how the `.allOf(…).thenApply(…)` approach defeats the purpose. The only thing that is missing, is to chain another `join()` to get the result list (which implies waiting for it).

Comment: @Holger the callback passed to`thenApply()` after `allOf` doesn't run until all futures wrapped in `allOf()` complete. that means calling `join()` on those futures in that callback has no meaning as far as forcing the system to wait for results is concerned (all `join()` does there is get results from already completed futures, it doesn't cause a wait). The sentence can be better phrased, I realize, but that is what I meant. I already suggested the `join()` call you're suggesting in the last snippet, but I just don't like the double calls to that method.

Comment: SHould we call loop from inside a completablefuture or a completablefuture inside a loop? 
Which approach is better? 
When I call a loop from inside a completableFuture.applyAsync then I need to use join() twice